# Was Galadriel ever jealous of Arwen's beauty?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, elves

Is there anything in the books or movies which seem to indicate that Galadriel was jealous of Arwen's beauty? Especially since Galadriel is extremely prideful of her beauty? Like in

> I am beautiful and terrible as the dawn

Comment: Can you please provide a quote or two to back up your supposition.

Comment: Why should she?

Comment: You remember that Arwen is Galadriel's granddaughter, right?

Comment: That quote in and of itself gives no indication that she's proud of her beauty.  A person can make a truthful, factual statment about themselves without it  being prideful.

Answer (score 6):

**No, there is no evidence in the books OR movies that Galadriel is envious of Arwen. Or even vain.**

Galadriel is one of the oldest living elves on Middle Earth, if not the oldest. She is considered wise beyond measure, and is well aware that others think her beautiful. There are entire legends & songs about the beauty of Lady Galadriel, and she knows this. This is not vanity, but rather a simple acknowledgement of fact.

We don't even know if Galadriel perceives HERSELF as beautiful. In the line you reference, she is stating how others would perceive her (if she took the ring & became queen):

> And now at last it comes. You will give me the Ring freely! In place
>   of the Dark Lord you will set up a Queen. And I shall not be dark, but
>   beautiful and terrible as the Morning and the Night! Fair as the Sea
>   and the Sun and the Snow upon the Mountain! Dreadful as the Storm and
>   the Lightning! Stronger than the foundations of the earth. All shall
>   love me and despair!

If anything, the very fact the she knows this and STILL resists the temptation of the ring is ample evidence that she is not vain. A woman ruled by vanity would not choose to diminish & fade away.

Comment: Galadriel is one of the oldest, but not the OLDEST in middle earth. That honour goes to Cirdan Shipwright of Lindon